# Does an Indian citizen need a Hong Kong transit visa for a 2 hour layover?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, hong-kong

I am traveling to Taiwan via HongKong, where I have a change of flights. I would be in the airport for 2 and a half hours [layover].

**So, would I be needing a transit visa for Hong Kong?**

PS : I have tried going through a lot of docs, but haven't really got a clear information regarding short transits

My itinerary :

> Mumbai [Terminal 2] -Jet Airways-> Hong Kong [Terminal 1] --- 2hr 20
>   min layover --> Hong Kong [Terminal 1] -HK Airlines-> Taiwan [Terminal
>   2]
>
> Taiwan [Terminal 2]] -HK airlines-> Hong Kong [Terminal 1] --- 2hr 50
>   min layover --> Hong Kong [Terminal 2] -Jet Airways-> Taiwan [Terminal
>   2]

**All the above flights are booked at the same time i.e. both my Jet flights have same PNR and both my HK airlines have same PNR.**

Comment: **Important question**: were **all** of your flights booked in **a single booking**?

Comment: @Crazydre I have added that in bold in my qn.  :) . I mean, **I booked all 4 tickets in a single booking**

Comment: Good, then my answer stands :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always refer to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=hk&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, about these things:

> Visa required, **except** for those who are in direct (Air to Air
>   or Air to Sea) transit if holding confirmed onward bookings,
>   continuing their journey within 48 hours and not leaving the
>   transit lounge.

So no, you do **not** need a visa

Comment: If I read the itinerary correctly, on the way back (s)he has to change from Hong Kong terminal 1 to terminal 2.  That's not possible whilst staying airside, surely?

Comment: Also "Both my Jet flights have the same PNR and HK flights have same PNR" _might_ imply that there are two separate bookings (Mumbai-HK-Mumbai on Jet and HK-Taiwan-HK on HK). In this case, OP will have to retrieve and check-in luggage at HK which means leaving airside.

Comment: @MadHatter If there was such a restriction, it would be clearly noted in Timatic.

Comment: @RedBaron OP said all flights were booked at the same time, so it should be through-checked. But I'll ask

Comment: @Crazydre I suspect it is: "*Visa required, except for those who are in direct ... transit ... and not leaving the transit lounge*".  My question is whether you can transfer between terminals without leaving the transit lounge.

Comment: @MadHatter "My question is whether you can transfer between terminals without leaving the transit Lounge" **Again**, if you couldn't, **it would be clearly stated in Timatic**. Click on the link and replace HK with AZ in the URL. You'll see that, at Baku Airport in Azerbaijan, you **cannot** switch terminals airside. Or why not put FR? At the Paris-Orly, Nice and Lyon airports it's the same, and **clearly stated**

Comment: @Crazydre that makes excellent sense, and thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Hey @Crazydre. I have a similar itinerary. Would your answer hold true for my case? Here's the StackExchange question https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94334/61908

Comment: @TasdikRahman Yes, 100%

Answer (score 0):

**No. Not needed.**

The Hong Kong station has an MRT-like underground train service which the passengers can use for commuting from one terminal to another.

The officers in the stations are also very helpful. They would look at your boarding passes and would tell you which station you need to get down at.

Thus, one doesn't need to cross over the airside. So, the transit visa is not required in this case. [Timatic is perfectly right, as the accepted answer quotes.]