# Does an Indian citizen need a Bangkok transit visa for a 10h 45m layover?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, bangkok

My itinerary

> Bengaluru(Thai Airways International) --> Bangkok --> 01h15m layover
>   --> Bangkok(Thai Airways International) --> Taipei(Terminal 1)

^ The flight numbers being different

While coming back from Taiwan, it would be

> Taipei(Terminal 1)(Thai Airways International) --> Bangkok --> 10h45m
>   stop --> Bangkok (Thai Airways International) --> Bengaluru

^ The flight numbers being different

**So, would I be needing a transit visa for Bangkok?**

I just got my stamped passport back from the Taiwan embassy with the visitor VISA stamp.

**NOTE: All the above flights are booked at the same time i.e. both my Thai Airways International have the same PNR.**

**EDIT** I got this off from the [timatic database](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=bkk&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX#)

> National India (IN)             /Transit Thailand (TH)
>
> Thailand (TH)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of
>   onward tickets for a max.
>
> transit For details, click here time of 12 hours through Bangkok
>   Suvarnabhumi (BKK). Passengers must have a connecting flight
>
> booked on the same ticket.
>
> - This does not apply when traveling on Angkor Air (K6),    Beijing Capital Airlines (JD), Business Air (8B), Cebu    Pacific (5J),
>     Eaststar Jet (ZE), Golden Myanmar Airlines    (Y5), Hong Kong Airlines
>     (HX), Indigo (6E), Jeju Air (7C),    Jet Asia Airways (JF), Jetstar
>     (JQ), Jetstar Pacific (BL),    Jin Air (LJ), JuneYao Airlines (HO),
>     Lao Central Airlines    (LF), Mandara Airlines (RI), Norwegian Air
>     (DY), Okay    Airways BK), Orient Thai Airlines (OX), Regent Air (RX),
>     Shandong Airlines (SC), Shanghai Airlines (FM), Shenzhen    Airlines
>     (ZH), Siberia Airlines (S7), Sichuan Airlines    (3U), South East
>     Asian Airlines (DG), Spice Jet (SG), Thai    Smile Airlines (WE),
>     Tianjin Airlines (GS), Tiger Air (TR),    Trans Aero (UN),
>     Turkmenistan Airlines (T5), T'way Airlines    (TW), Ural Airlines (U6)
>     and VietJet Air (VJ).  Visa required, except for Holders of onward
>     tickets for a max.
>
> transit For details, click here time of 12 hours through Bangkok Don
>   Mueang (DMK) when traveling on Thai AirAsia (FD) or Thai AirAsia X
>   (XJ). Passengers must have a connecting flight
>
> booked on the same ticket.

Comment: Was my answer right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break timatic's statement into further sentences:

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit For details, click here time of 12 hours through Bangkok Suvarnabhumi (BKK)

So, as your transit is `<= 12 hours`, you are good here.

> **This does not apply when traveling on** Angkor Air (K6), Beijing Capital Airlines (JD), Business Air (8B), Cebu Pacific (5J), Eaststar Jet (ZE), Golden Myanmar Airlines (Y5), Hong Kong Airlines (HX), Indigo (6E), Jeju Air (7C), Jet Asia Airways (JF), Jetstar (JQ), Jetstar Pacific (BL), Jin Air (LJ), JuneYao Airlines (HO), Lao Central Airlines (LF), Mandara Airlines (RI), Norwegian Air (DY), Okay Airways BK), Orient Thai Airlines (OX), Regent Air (RX), Shandong Airlines (SC), Shanghai Airlines (FM), Shenzhen Airlines (ZH), Siberia Airlines (S7), Sichuan Airlines (3U), South East Asian Airlines (DG), Spice Jet (SG), Thai Smile Airlines (WE), Tianjin Airlines (GS), Tiger Air (TR), Trans Aero (UN), Turkmenistan Airlines (T5), T'way Airlines (TW), Ural Airlines (U6) and VietJet Air (VJ). Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max.

So, as you are traveling via the **Thai Airways**, the above is not applicable, which means the previous statement stands.

**Thus, you don't need a transit visa for this itinerary**

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a visa since it's just a layover in BKK. However you won't be able to leave the airport area and will have to wait for your next flight inside the terminal. 11 hours is a very long time to just sit around inside the airport terminal.

If you plan to explore Bangkok during your layover - you can apply for VISA ON ARRIVAL right there at the airport. The fee is 1,000 Thai Baht - you just fill up an application and make sure to have 1 passport size photo with you.
Obviously if your flight from Taipei arrives late in the evening or at night - you're better off just staying inside the terminal. If you arrive in BKK during the day - then it's worth applying for the visa on arrival.
You don't have to collect any checked luggage. You'll have enough time to leave the airport, wander around Bangkok for few hours and get back to Suvarnabhumi Airport to continue your trip to India.