# Is transit visa required in Suvarnabhumi airport, Bangkok?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand, vietnam, connecting-flights

I am travelling from Ho Chi Minh to Mumbai by connecting flight. I'm on Thai Airways from Ho Chi Minh to Bangkok and Jet Airways from Bangkok to Mumbai.
There is 3.30 mins layover at BKK airport. Do I need a transit visa? I have to cross emigration to collect the baggage.

Is 3 hours 30 minutes time enough to catch the connecting flight from Bangkok?

Comment: Did you buy separate tickets, then?

Answer (score 5):

My reading of our [earlier answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94334/does-an-indian-citizen-need-a-bangkok-transit-visa-for-a-10h-45m-layover) is that you will need a full visa, not a transit visa, if you leave the sterile zone to collect and re-check luggage. If your tickets are on one reservation *and* you check your luggage through to India, you can stay airside and do not need any visa whatsoever. You are eligible for a [visa on arrival](http://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand/visa-on-arrival.php) at a cost of 2000 Thai Baht.

3:30 should be enough time between flights if your first arrival is timely. Travelling on two tickets always has the risk of misconnecting at your own cost to fix.